# The name does not exist in the namespace despite being there

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to use data binding to create a list view but get this error. Why does the following error appear even though the affected name is actually in the affected class?

> The name "ListItem" does not exist in the namespace "using:My_App.Models".

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="My_App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:My_App.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

        <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind listItems}" 
            ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"
            SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:ListItem">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookTitle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using My_App.Models;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Email;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace My_App
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private List<ListItem> listItems;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            listItems = ItemManager.GetListItems();
        }
    }
}
```

**ListItem class (inside the 'Models' folder)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My_App.Models
{

    public class ListItem
    {
        public string BookTitle { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemManager
    {
        public static List<ListItem> GetListItems()
        {
            var items = new List<ListItem>
            {
                new ListItem { BookTitle = "The Wizard of Oz" }
            };

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `using` inside `xmlns`?

Comment: Please check  if `xmlns:data="using:My_App.Models"` is correct reference.  I made a code sample with above, your code looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The name does not exist in the namespace despite being there

For checking your code, I found you have missed  `My_App.Models` namespace in `MainPage` class. I make a code [sample here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/My_App/blob/master/My_App/MainPage.xaml.cs#L1), and it works well please check it.

If the problem persists, please try to delete the project's bin and obj folder and build the solution before launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, but changing `Binding` to `x:Bind` helped to compile the project.
Also, there was second error with `private List<ListItem> listItems;`. It has to be public. So:

```xml
<StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind BookTitle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

and

```cs
public List<ListItem> listItems;
```